# Typechecking not working with VsCode on .ts files

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

**My environment:**

- Visual Code: 1.27.2
- typescript: 3.1.1
- tslint: 5.11.0

I am writing this simple erroneous of code in a file called `server.ts`:

```
let isDone: boolean = "done"
```

After running `tsc` I am getting the compiler error i expect to see:

```
src/server.ts:1:5 - error TS2322: Type '1' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

However, looking at the problems pane of Vscode does not warn me of this error. there are no problems reported and no error are being highlighed on the editor.

Is type checking supported in anyway in Vscode?

Comment: It works for me.  What do you see in the "TypeScript" page of the "Output" tab of the bottom panel?

Comment: nothing special. it prints the PATH , and finally: `[Info  - 2:32:37 AM] Started TSServer`

Comment: Do you get other hover information?  For example, if you hover over `isDone`, do you get a popup with `let isDone: boolean`?  Do you have large or complex files in the project that might be hanging the tsserver?  Make sure you haven't set the VS Code `typescript.validate.enable` setting to false.  Then try setting `typescript.tsserver.trace` to `verbose` and look in the output panel again.

Comment: horray! it was `typescript.validate.enable` turned off.  if you want you can post it as answer and i will accept this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resolution was to turn on the `typescript.validate.enable` setting in VS Code, which is on by default but had somehow been turned off.